# The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.web

I have `asp.net core 2.2` project. I want to use `System.Web` in my project but when i try to use this in my controller so it says like this

> The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\Projects\analytics\analytics.csproj]

I have project.csproj file like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="IpGeoLocation.IpGeoLocation" Version="1.0.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Web" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" 
  />
  <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.7.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
  <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.Core" Version="2.7.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
  <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Bson" Version="2.7.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I am using `System.Web` because i am implementing third party plugin `ipinfo` to get user's location based on `ip` address. So in my controller my function is like

```
string ipInfoBaseUrl = "http://ipinfo.io/";
string userIpAddress = "66.54.123.13";
string ipUrl = ipInfoBaseUrl + userIpAddress;
string ipResponse = IPRequestHelper(ipUrl);
return ipResponse;
```

My helper function is like

```
public string IPRequestHelper(string url)
{
        string checkURL = url;
        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();

        StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());

        string responseRead = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

        responseRead = responseRead.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
        responseStream.Close();
        responseStream.Dispose();

        return responseRead;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Code. How can i get rid of this error?

Comment: Why do you want to use that namespace? What class are you trying to make use of?

Comment: I am implementing third party plugin to get user's geo location based on ip address. So in that article he is using System.Web. So in asp.net what should i use instead of System.Web?

Comment: Use `HttpClient` or `IHttpClientFactory` instead of `WebRequest`. Besides, I don't see any `System.Web.UI` stuff in your code.

Comment: can you convert my `IPRequestHelper` using `HttpClient` because i don't know how to use that. I am new to asp.net core

Comment: Check instructions [here](https://ipgeolocation.io/documentation/ip-geolocation-api-c-sharp-dotnet-sdk.html). Should work from ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That namespace belongs to ASP.NET Web Pages and isn't part of .NET Core, hence you cannot use it in an ASP.NET Core project.

Your options are ASP.NET Core razor pages, or Blazor.

If you're using a 3rd party library that depends on legacy .NET Framework (non-Core), you may want to switch-back and use classic ASP.NET instead.

For IP address in the .NET Framework, use the [`System.Net.IPAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress) class

Looks like the [`IpGeoLocation.IpGeoLocation`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IpGeoLocation.IpGeoLocation) package has no dependencies but on JSON.NET, so you should probably be able to use it from ASP.NET Core.

#### Update

Replace that code with the following:

```
public async Task<string> GetIpGeoLocationAsync(string url)
{
  using (var cl = new HttpClient())
    return await cl.GetStringAsync(url);
}
```

Also, consider using [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests) instead.

Comment: I am implementing third party plugin to get user's `geo` location based on `ip address`. So in that article he is using `System.Web`. So in `asp.net` what should i use instead of `System.Web`?

Comment: I have updated my question please see and suggest me that how can i get user `geo` location i.e (city, country, etc) in asp.net core 2.2

Comment: after adding `services.AddHttpClient();` in `startup.cs` in my controller what should i import to use `IHttpClientFactor` ?

Comment: @FahadHassan, assuming you're using the `HttpClient` in a controller, add `IHttpClientFactory` to your controller's constructor parameters and store it in a private field. Instead of create a `new HttpClient` use `_HttpClientFactory.CreateClient`, see example [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/stevejgordon/41b1c75e6f4eca8feca82ec543cd2fac/raw/9ca7a8c21666a81413c60d7b6aa995763fa0758e/ValuesController.cs).